# index locator error IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, gspread

I'm writing python code to access data from a google sheet using `gspread`.

```
    import gspread
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
    from pprint import pprint
    import pandas as pd
    scope =['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)

    sheet = client.open("tutorial") # Open the spreadhseet
    worksheet = sheet.get_worksheet(1)
    data = pd.DataFrame(worksheet.get_all_records()) 
    car = "car"
    mpg = "mpg"
    city_mpg_data = data[data['city mpg'] == mpg]
    car_city_mpg_data = city_mpg_data[city_mpg_data['Make'] == car]
    car_city_mpg_data = car_city_mpg_data.reset_index()
    get = car_city_mpg_data.iloc[2]

    print("Okay. You are looking for {} {}.".format(get[6], get[8]))
```

I'm getting the error:

> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds.
>   Kindly suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please add full traceback, including reported line number for your code.

Answer (score 0):

`IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds` means you are trying to access element which doesn't exist.

Quick google search reveals, that this is an error raised by pandas dataframes `iloc` method.

`get = car_city_mpg_data.iloc[2]` methods tries to access third dataframe row, when there are less.

I'd add `print(car_city_mpg_data)` before that line and investigate from there.